# OpenSAML: how to get entityID of MetadataProvider?

Tags: opensaml

I have AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider object that corresponds to IdP and I need to get its entityID. How do I get it? Is there a way to avoid nasty XML parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way that requires a (potentially unsafe?) typecast.

```
MetadataProvider provider = ...
String entityID = ((EntityDescriptor) provider.getMetadata()).getEntityID()
```

Is there a better way?